# JavaScript can't read data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have weird issues from my firebase. at 9PM JKT time i still can access my Firebase from HTML, but 50 minutes later my HTML can read my Firebase database with same code. I just realize if Firebase update into 4.0.0 at that night. first, i think i have from code with my firebase, so i ask for support from Firebase and they answer my code is good and he can retrive data from database. he sugest me to clean cache on my browser, but still my html can't read database.
this is my code

```
var suhu = document.querySelector('temp');
var config = {
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var suhuRef = firebase.database().ref('sensor').child('suhu');
suhuRef.on('value', function (datasnapshot) { 
    suhu.innerHTML = datasnapshot.val();
});
```

is this normal ?
i change my isp but still can't retrive data. i check from Developer tools on Firefox, it's look same, no error.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsbin.com/jutuka/edit?js,console

Comment: hai @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for your help, i have just fixed, changed my rules from "auth != null" into "true".

Comment: That means that the problem started when you changed your security rules and is unrelated to the SDK change.

Comment: i have same config before and after Firebase update, all with auth, but still i can't retrive my data.